# IP Camera OpenCV Image Overread

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera

I have difficulties to process IP Camera images on my RPI 4 (even on my Mac) with OpenCV and Python. My project is to acquire IP Camera images (RGB - 1920 x 1080) and process them with object detection algorithm. I don’t have any real time constraint. If I could run the algorithm about every 5 min, it would be perfect.

OpenCV version: 4.1.1
Python version : 3.6.5

First of all, I tested the algorithm with an image bank that I previously recorded (from the same camera). It perfectly worked.

Nevertheless, once I tried to use the video stream I got an error about overreading. I guess, I should have a problem about the way I manage the image flow.

```
import cv2, time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(‘URL’)
if (cap.isOpened()== False):
        print("Error opening video stream or file")

sampleTime = 10 # in seconds
imgCounter = 0
startTime = time.time()

while True:
        ret, frameCaptured = cap.read()

        if time.time() - startTime >= sampleTime and ret == True:
                startTime = time.time()

                # Do some stuff here
                time.sleep(5)
                cv2.imshow('Captured Image', frameCaptured)
                imgCounter += 1
                print("Image:",imgCounter)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Even if the first image is normally recorded, I systematically get an error:
Image: 1
[mjpeg @ 0x7ff6ac808000] overread 8

Then the variable "ret" becomes False. 
Note that without the condition “ret == True”, I see a green area appearing on the second image and then the execution stops.

Comment: Can you post your full error?

Comment: Please check your formatting - indentation is significant in Python.

Comment: Sorry for the indentation, I fixed it. With the code I posted I got: MacBook-Pro-...$ python3 ~/Desktop/test.py
> Image: 1
> [mjpeg @ 0x7f990f81ac00] overread 8.
Then it never stops since "ret=False"

Comment: have you solved this problem? I am experiencing the same @Pm22

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem reading from an IP camera and found that I was initially setting my image size to VGA and then downsizing it later to QVGA.

(Code below is from the IP camera rather than PC side)

```
if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 8;
    config.fb_count = 2;
    Serial.print("PSRAM FOUND");


// camera init etc

sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
// drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_VGA);
```

Hence, opencv is attempting to fit a QVGA image into a VGA box resulting in overreading. This is my best guess and may not be entirely accurate but fixed my error.